# Converting a string to and from Base 64

Tags: python-3.x, base64

I am trying to write two programs one that converts a string to base64 and then another that takes a base64 encoded string and converts it back to a string.
so far i cant get past the base64 encoding part as i keep getting the error

```
TypeError: expected bytes, not str
```

my code looks like this so far

```
def convertToBase64(stringToBeEncoded):
import base64
EncodedString= base64.b64encode(stringToBeEncoded)
return(EncodedString)
```

Comment: Since python-3 has unicode string, the bytes datatype was introduced. You have to convert your string to a bytearray, e.g. by using `b = bytes(mystring, 'utf-8')`, and then using `b` for the encoding: `EncodedString = base64.b64encode(b)`, which will return a bytearray

Comment: This same problem plagued me for most of a day, until I stumbled across this little nugget: https://stackabuse.com/encoding-and-decoding-base64-strings-in-python/  (I wanted to post an answer here, but the post has been closed as duplicate.  Sorry, but the linked post doesn't address this question--even though the answer may be related.)

Answer (score 52):

A string is already 'decoded', thus the str class has no 'decode' function.Thus:

```
AttributeError: type object 'str' has no attribute 'decode'
```

If you want to decode a byte array and turn it into a string call:

```
the_thing.decode(encoding)
```

If you want to encode a string (turn it into a byte array) call:

```
the_string.encode(encoding)
```

In terms of the base 64 stuff:
Using 'base64' as the value for encoding above yields the error:

```
LookupError: unknown encoding: base64
```

Open a console and type in the following:

```
import base64
help(base64)
```

You will see that base64 has two very handy functions, namely b64decode and b64encode. b64 decode returns a byte array and b64encode requires a bytes array.

To convert a string into it's base64 representation you first need to convert it to bytes. I like utf-8 but use whatever encoding you need...

```
import base64
def stringToBase64(s):
    return base64.b64encode(s.encode('utf-8'))

def base64ToString(b):
    return base64.b64decode(b).decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: This is also good reminder for those doing transition to py3x from py2x uu917soki00vung.